# Unique value through two columns

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique

Is there any constraint in MySQL in order to avoid from entering the same value in the same column or in another column?
For example, in the following table:

```
   --------------------
   |       TABLE       |
   ---------------------
   | NUMBER1 | NUMBER2 |
   ---------------------
   |    3    |   4     |
   |    7    |   9     |
   ---------------------
```

I need to prevent the number 3 from being entered in any of the columns NUMBER1 or NUMBER2, since the value already exists in column NUMBER1; and that the number 9 cannot be ingested in either of the columns NUMBER1 or NUMBER2, since the value already exists in column NUMBER2.

In other words, I need that each value in each of the two columns be unique, through those two columns.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll probably need `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers as you won't be able to do that with an index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an indirect solution.  You may refactor the design of your table such that it uses only a single column for both current columns.  Then, introduce some sort of group columns to keep track of the relationships between the numbers from a given record.  That is:

```
grp | pos | NUMBER
1   | 1   | 3
1   | 2   | 4
2   | 1   | 7
2   | 2   | 9
```

Now you only need a unique constraint on the single `NUMBER` column.  Note that if you want to view your data as it appears now, a simple pivot query can handle that:

```
SELECT
    grp,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pos = 1 THEN NUMBER END) AS NUMBER1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pos = 2 THEN NUMBER END) AS NUMBER2
FROM newTable
GROUP BY
    grp;
```

Comment: It's not possible to refactor the table in that way.
Thank you, any way, Tim!

Comment: Then see Nick's comment about needing triggers.  The design I am suggesting is possibly more efficient than what you have right now, and your requirement of a unique constraint across two columns might imply a lack of normalization.