# Unique values in two columns not related per row

Tags: postgresql, mikro-orm

Related: [Unique value through two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108325/unique-value-through-two-columns)

---

In PostgreSQL, I need to make sure that each value in two columns is unique, for example, `ip_1` and `ip_2` are columns and each IP address in both columns in any row should be unique (or `NULL`). How can I accomplish this?

As a side question, if someone knows, how can accomplish this in Mikro-ORM (within Nest.js + TypeScript), it’d be awesome, however, this is not that much important (now).

Comment: Use only one column and a regular unique constraint.

Comment: Imagine a device with two network interfaces while each network interface is used for different purposes. But not every device has both interfaces, so I need to know _exactly_ which interfaces is being utilised (be it `ip_1` or `ip_2`; the other, non-utilised would be `NULL`). Yes, I could create an `ip` column with an array type or comma separated IP addresses, but I think that further complicates it. If you have a specific solution in mind, give an answer with some example. Thanks anyway. :wink:

Comment: No, no (further) denormalization, no arrays nor comma separated lists (which won't help you with the uniqueness problem anyway)! Have one table with one column referencing the device (or several columns, if a device's primary key consists of more than one column), one for exactly one address and another for the interface number (or whatever designation). If a device has two interfaces there are two *rows* in that table for that device. If it has three, it's three rows and so on...

Comment: I see what you mean, but I have a requirement to have _exactly_ one row per device in the device table.

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be a requirement dictating how the logical database model has to look like, that's solely the database's business. What you probably need is a view (or a bunch of them) that act as an interface to the user/application which may dictate the form. For the devices that view would join the device table and interface table in a way producing one row per device.

Comment: True that nothing should dictate how the logical database model has to look like, however I am not able to change this at the moment. I need to refactor the app as little as possible for backwards compatibility. Then we can talk about full rewrite. Now I only need to validate that an IP address is not used in neither of the columns before its insertion into one of them.